# How to add tabulate table into pdf page using fpdf

Tags: python

I have  implemented a simple table using library [tabulate](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/), am now attempting to print this table that has table format `fancy_grid` using fpdf but am getting the following error, how can I add this table to the pdf??

Error

```
  File "E:\Developement\Desktop Applications\GuiWithWx\venv\lib\site-packages\fpdf\fpdf.py", line 1170, in _putpages
    p = self.pages[n].encode("latin1") if PY3K else self.pages[n] 
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 388-425: ordinal not in range(256)
```

The Table

[image]

My Code

```
from fpdf import FPDF
from tabulate import tabulate
import webbrowser


def pdf_Example_Two():
    title = '20000 Leagues Under the Seas'

    class PDF(FPDF):
        def header(self):
            # Arial bold 15
            self.set_font('Arial', 'B', 15)
            # Calculate width of title and position
            w = self.get_string_width(title) + 6
            self.set_x((210 - w) / 2)
            # Colors of frame, background and text
            self.set_draw_color(0, 80, 180)
            self.set_fill_color(230, 230, 0)
            self.set_text_color(220, 50, 50)
            # Thickness of frame (1 mm)
            self.set_line_width(1)
            # Title
            self.cell(w, 9, title, 1, 1, 'C', 1)
            # Line break
            self.ln(10)

        def footer(self):
            # Position at 1.5 cm from bottom
            self.set_y(-15)
            # Arial italic 8
            self.set_font('Arial', 'I', 8)
            # Text color in gray
            self.set_text_color(128)
            # Page number
            self.cell(0, 10, 'Page ' + str(self.page_no()), 0, 0, 'C')

        def chapter_title(self, num, label):
            # Arial 12
            self.set_font('Arial', '', 12)
            # Background color
            self.set_fill_color(200, 220, 255)
            # Title
            self.cell(0, 6, 'Chapter %d : %s' % (num, label), 0, 1, 'L', 1)
            # Line break
            self.ln(4)

        def chapter_body(self, name):
            # Read text file
            with open(name, 'rb') as fh:
                txt = fh.read().decode('utf-8')
            # Times 12
            self.set_font('Times', '', 12)
            # Output justified text
            self.multi_cell(0, 5, txt)
            # Line break
            self.ln()
            # Mention in italics
            self.set_font('', 'I')
            self.cell(0, 5, '(end of excerpt)')

        def print_chapter(self, num, title, name):
            self.add_page()
            self.chapter_title(num, title)
            self.chapter_body(name)

    l = [["Hassan", 21, "LUMS"], ["Ali", 22, "FAST"], ["Ahmed", 23, "UET"]]
    table = tabulate(l, headers=['Name', 'Age', 'University'], tablefmt='fancy_grid', showindex="always")
    print(table)
    print('\n\n\n\n')

    with open("C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\kaita.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as outf:
        outf.write(table)


    pdf = PDF()
    pdf.set_title(title)
    pdf.set_author('Jules Verne')
    pdf.print_chapter(1, 'A RUNAWAY REEF', 'C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\kaita.txt')
    pdf.output('tuto3.pdf', 'F')
    webbrowser.open_new(f"tuto3.pdf")


pdf_Example_Two()
```